# Нужны здесь запятые?

Tags: запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, требуется ли в данном контексте запятая:

"С 10.07.2023 у нас работает Иванов Иван в отделе по анализу данных аналитиком."

или

"С 10.07.2023 у нас работает Иванов Иван в отделе по анализу данных, аналитиком."

Comment: Ответы в комментариях запрещены

Answer (score 0):

Запятую, конечно, поставить нужно. Но предложение лучше перестроить, т.к. оно имеет разговорный характер.

С 10.07.2023 у нас в отделе по анализу данных  Иванов Иван  работает аналитиком.

Comment: Так себе получилось. Тоже не по-русски.

Comment: А что для вас по-русски?

Comment: Например, вот это: *Иванов Иван работает у нас аналитиком в отделе по анализу данных с 10.07.2023.*

Comment: А вам известно,что такое тема-рема?

Comment: Да.............

Comment: Просто переставьте "Иванов Иван" в конец, и будет по-русски.

Comment: Ну вот и прекрасно. А теперь поймите, в чем разница между моим предложением и вашим.

Comment: В том, что моё удачное по стилистике, а ваше — нет. Если у вас ударение на "Иван", то это не подходит для делового стиля.

Comment: Ну да, у вас всегда все удачно, в отличии от других.

Comment: Потому что, в отличи**е** от других, не использую не по-русски составленные фразы.

Comment: Ну вы даже маститых лингвистов критикуете. Ладно, что с вами спорить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147193/discussion-between--and-oleedd).

Comment: Всего лишь один раз. Это ерунда. Другие сильнее критиковали. Ajgy вообще считает Ушакова и Ефремову некомпетентными.

Comment: Да уж... вроде бы Ушаков и Ефремова занимались преимущественно толовым словарями, а не стилистикой. Чтобы говорить о корректном построении предложения. надо знать коммуникативную сторону этого сообщения. Другими словами, кто, кому и зачем это пишет, какого рода информация здесь содержится. Эта фраза как бы  ответ на вопрос, которого мы не видим.

Answer (score 0):

В сочетании ‟работает аналитиком” слово ‟аналитиком” является дополнением, дополнения не обособляются. Это слово может обособляться, если будет являться присоединением, то есть когда предложение произнесётся полностью, а после произнесения автор захочет добавить слово ‟аналитиком”.

Comment: Дополнение к слову данных?